# Extraneous Django DB Queries on user.has_perms(perms)

Tags: django, django-orm, django-authentication

Looking at the SQL queries run when `user.has_perms(perms)` is called, I see:

```
SELECT "auth_permission"."id", 
       "auth_permission"."name", 
       "auth_permission"."content_type_id", 
       "auth_permission"."codename", 
       "django_content_type"."id", 
       "django_content_type"."name", 
       "django_content_type"."app_label", 
       "django_content_type"."model" 
FROM   "auth_permission" 
       inner join "auth_user_user_permissions" 
               ON ( "auth_permission"."id" = 
                    "auth_user_user_permissions"."permission_id" ) 
       inner join "django_content_type" 
               ON ( "auth_permission"."content_type_id" = 
                    "django_content_type"."id" ) 
WHERE  "auth_user_user_permissions"."user_id" = %s 
ORDER  BY "django_content_type"."app_label" ASC, 
          "django_content_type"."model" ASC, 
          "auth_permission"."codename" ASC
```

and:

```
SELECT "django_content_type"."app_label", 
       "auth_permission"."codename" 
FROM   "auth_permission" 
       inner join "auth_group_permissions" 
               ON ( "auth_permission"."id" = 
                    "auth_group_permissions"."permission_id" ) 
       inner join "auth_group" 
               ON ( "auth_group_permissions"."group_id" = "auth_group"."id" ) 
       inner join "auth_user_groups" 
               ON ( "auth_group"."id" = "auth_user_groups"."group_id" ) 
       left outer join "django_content_type" 
                    ON ( "auth_permission"."content_type_id" = 
                         "django_content_type"."id" ) 
WHERE  "auth_user_groups"."user_id" = %s
```

my questions are:

1. What exactly are these queries doing?
2. Why are they run on
   every request? Is there some way to cache these results?